# Automorphism of an open subset with completement of codimension $2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, automorphism-group

Let $\mathbb P^n=\mathbb {CP^n}$, I guess the following is true:

> Let $D\subset \mathbb P^n$ be a closed subscheme of codimension $2$. Then every automorphism of $\mathbb P^n-D$ is linear, i.e.
>    ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb P^n-D)\subset {\rm Aut}(\mathbb P^n)$.

More generally, I guess the following is also true:

> Let $D\subset V$ be a closed subscheme of codimension $2$, here $V$ is an arbitrary variety. Then ${\rm Aut}(V-D)\subset {\rm Aut}(V)$.

Is it correct? Could someone give a reference or counter example about this?

I think the codimension $2$ condition is for Hartog's theorem, but I do not know how to apply it. Clearly we can not expect any morphism to extend to $D$, as there may be base locus, so we really need automorphisms. Also, it is not enough if $D$ is of codimension $1$, since there is trivial counter-example $\mathbb P^n-D=\mathbb A^n$.

Comment: If $V$ is an *affine* *normal* variety and $D\subset V$ is a closed subscheme of codimension at least two, then every morphism $V\subset D \to V$ extends (uniqutely) to a morphism $V\to V$ by Hartog's theorem. In particular, $\mathrm{Aut}(V-D) = \mathrm{Aut}(V)$ under these assumptions.

Comment: Dear @AriyanJavanpeykar: (The automorphism should send $D$ to $D$, so we only get ${\rm Aut}(V-D)\subset {\rm Aut}(V)$, but this is not important). Yes, but I am mainly interested in the case $V=\mathbb P^n$, so we do not have the affineness.